# Is there a built-in Mathematica function to find operators rather than numbers in equations?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

How can the following be best accomplished in Mathematica?

```
 In[1] := Solve[f[2,3]==5,f ∈ {Plus,Minus,Divide}]

Out[1] := Plus
```

Comment: In fact you can achieve much more than this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947937/algorithm-for-permutations-of-operators-and-operands/3948113#3948113

Comment: the linked question was already among my favs o__O ... thx for the link!

Comment: I am not sure what you intended, but it is possible that you are confusing `Minus` and `Subtract`, FYI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The desired expression syntax can be transformed into a set of `Solve` expressions:

```
fSolve[expr_, f_ ∈ functions_List] :=
  Map[Solve[(expr /. f -> #) && f == #, f] &, functions] // Flatten
```

Sample use:

```
In[6]:= fSolve[f[2,3] == 5, f ∈ {Plus, Subtract, Divide}]
Out[6]= {f -> Plus}

In[7]:= fSolve[f[4,2] == 2, f ∈ {Plus, Subtract, Divide}]
Out[7]= {f -> Subtract, f -> Divide}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the full power of `Solve` remains available for more complex expressions, e.g.

```
In[8]:= fSolve[D[f[x], x] < f[x], f ∈ {Log, Exp}]
Out[8]= {f -> ConditionalExpression[Log, x Log[x]∈Reals && x>E^ProductLog[1]]}

In[9]:= fSolve[D[f[x], x] <= f[x], f ∈ {Log, Exp}]
Out[9]= {f -> ConditionalExpression[Log, x Log[x]∈Reals && x>=E^ProductLog[1]],
         f -> ConditionalExpression[Exp, E^x ∈ Reals]}
```

Comment: Also very nice solution, good integration with standard Solve

Comment: Very nice.  I wish I'd thought of that. +1

Answer (score 6):

Please tell me if this does what you want:

```
findFunction[expr_, head_ ∈ {ops__}] :=
    Quiet@Pick[{ops}, expr /. head -> # & /@ {ops}]

findFunction[f[2, 3] == 5, f ∈ {Plus, Minus, Divide}]
```

```
(* Out[]= {Plus} *)
```

Comment: By the way, I know the answer is returned as a list, but since it is conceivable that more than one function will match, I think it should not return only the first one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a built-in function, but it's not hard to write one yourself. Here is one approach that you can use:

```
Clear@correctOperatorQ;
correctOperatorQ[expr_, value_, 
  operators_] := (expr == value) /. Head[expr] -> # & /@ operators
```

By the way, the correct operator for `2-3` is `Subtract`, not `Minus`. The result for your example:

```
correctOperatorQ[f[2, 3], 5, {Plus,Subtract,Divide}]
Out[1]={True, False, False}
```