# smallest integer not obtainable from {2,3,4,5,6,7,8} (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve the following problem using Mathematica:

What is the smallest positive integer not obtainable from the set `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` via arithmetic operations `{+,-,*,/}`, exponentiation, and parentheses.  Each number in the set must be used exactly once.  Unary operations are NOT allowed (1 cannot be converted to -1 with without using a 0, for example).

For example, the number `1073741824000000000000000` is obtainable via `(((3+2)*(5+4))/6)^(8+7)`.

I am a beginner with Mathematica.  I have written code that I believe solves the problems for the set `{2,3,4,5,6,7}` (I obtained 2249 as my answer), but my code is not efficient enough to work with the set `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`. (My code already takes 71 seconds to run on the set `{2,3,4,5,6,7}`)

I would very much appreciate any tips or solutions to solving this harder problem with Mathematica, or general insights as to how I could speed my existing code.

My existing code uses a brute force, recursive approach:

(* this defines combinations for a set of 1 number as the set of that 1 number  *)

```
combinations[list_ /; Length[list] == 1] := list
```

(* this tests whether it's ok to exponentiate two numbers including (somewhat) arbitrary restrictions to prevent overflow *)

```
oktoexponent[number1_, number2_] :=

 If[number1 == 0, number2 >= 0,
  If[number1 < 0,
   (-number1)^number2 < 10000 \[And] IntegerQ[number2],
   number1^number2 < 10000 \[And] IntegerQ[number2]]]
```

(* this takes a list and removes fractions with denominators greater than 100000 *)

```
cleanup[list_] := Select[list, Denominator[#] < 100000 &]
```

(* this defines combinations for a set of 2 numbers - and returns a set of all possible numbers obtained via applications of + - * / filtered by oktoexponent and cleanup rules *)

```
combinations[list_ /; Length[list] == 2 && Depth[list] == 2] :=
  cleanup[DeleteCases[#, Null] &@DeleteDuplicates@
    {list[[1]] + list[[2]],
     list[[1]] - list[[2]],
     list[[2]] - list[[1]],
     list[[1]]*list[[2]],
     If[oktoexponent[list[[1]], list[[2]]], list[[1]]^list[[2]],],
     If[oktoexponent[list[[2]], list[[1]]], list[[2]]^list[[1]],],
     If[list[[2]] != 0, list[[1]]/list[[2]],],
     If[list[[1]] != 0, list[[2]]/list[[1]],]}]
```

(* this extends combinations to work with sets of sets *)

```
combinations[
  list_ /; Length[list] == 2 && Depth[list] == 3] := 
 Module[{m, n, list1, list2},
  list1 = list[[1]];
  list2 = list[[2]];
  m = Length[list1]; n = Length[list2];
  cleanup[
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Flatten@Table[
      combinations[{list1[[i]], list2[[j]]}], {i, m}, {j, n}]]]
```

(* for a given set, partition returns the set of all partitions into two non-empty subsets *)

```
partition[list_] := Module[{subsets},
  subsets = Select[Subsets[list], # != {} && # != list &]; 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Table[Sort@{subsets[[i]], Complement[list, subsets[[i]]]}, {i, 
     Length[subsets]}]]
```

(* this finally extends combinations to work with sets of any size *)

```
combinations[list_ /; Length[list] > 2] := 
 Module[{partitions, k},
  partitions = partition[list];
  k = Length[partitions]; 
  cleanup[Sort@
    DeleteDuplicates@
     Flatten@(combinations /@ 
        Table[{combinations[partitions[[i]][[1]]], 
          combinations[partitions[[i]][[2]]]}, {i, k}])]]

Timing[desiredset = combinations[{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}];]

{71.5454, Null}

Complement[
   Range[1, 3000], #] &@(Cases[#, x_Integer /; x > 0 && x <= 3000] &@
   desiredset)

{2249, 2258, 2327, 2509, 2517, 2654, 2789, 2817, 2841, 2857, 2990, 2998}
```

Comment: Well, if you showed us your code rather than a rough sketch of it, some of us would cut and paste and fiddle around.

Comment: Somehow this sounds like a school assignment..

Comment: I'll post my code now - didn't post initially, just because I know I'm a beginner, and anticipate that optimal code would need to be wholly rewritten.  Jari, don't quite know what to say - it's not - I'm trying to learn Mathematica and have been going through the problems at Project Euler as a way of doing so.  This was a problem I'd personally set for myself in the same vein.

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3948113/353410

Comment: @belisarius: thank you for the link.  RPN in particular was useful to know about.  However I do not think that that approach would work for {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.  For {2,3,4,5,6,7} I believe your approach is comparable (if not slower) than my recursive approach.  Using your notation, the size of this new problem for a set of 7 numbers is `Binomial[7,2]*5!*132*5^6 = 5197500000`.  With 6 numbers, the size decreases to a more manageable: `Binomial[6,2]*4!*42*5^5 = 47250000`.

Comment: @Royce I only wanted to remind you about RPN, because it naturally solve the parenthesis problem. The link wasn't intended to give you a solution

Comment: I think you will first need a set of prime numbers and then exclude the +/- operations from it. Any prime number is not divisible by anything in that list. So only the additions and dettractions are to be considered.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ParallelComputing.html This might be helpful. You could recurse down different paths using other processes. On a separate note, could you avoid removing duplicates as much? I would imagine the 'DeleteDuplicates' command is computationally expensive. It _might_ be worth it to just remove duplicates once at the end.

Comment: This is interesting, but by nature of the kind of problem it looks to require a recursive algorythm. Now, maybe a pure mathematics person has a better mathematical appraoch. Did you look on some math sites?

Comment: @Royce, to confirm, this isn't a projecteuler.net problem, correct? In other words, you know of no online solution to this problem? My thoughts: I don't think you can safely throw away large intermediate results (overflows), since they might become small again. I would suggest a symbolic approach (not necessarily using Mathematica) where you simplify the symbols each round (ie, "2*3" and "3*2" are identical).

Comment: @barrycarter i can confirm it's not a projeceuler.net problem and have not been able to find an online solution.  fair point about the symbolic approach, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is unhelpful, but I'm under my quota for useless babbling today:

```
(* it turns out the symbolizing + * is not that useful after all *) 
f[x_,y_] = x+y 
fm[x_,y_] = x-y 
g[x_,y_] = x*y 
gd[x_,y_] = x/y 

(* power properties *) 
h[h[a_,b_],c_] = h[a,b*c] 
h[a_/b_,n_] = h[a,n]/h[b,n] 
h[1,n_] = 1 

(* expand simple powers only! *) 
(* does this make things worse? *) 
h[a_,2] = a*a 
h[a_,3] = a*a*a 

(* all symbols for two numbers *) 
allsyms[x_,y_] := allsyms[x,y] =  
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[{f[x,y], fm[x,y], fm[y,x],  
 g[x,y], gd[x,y], gd[y,x], h[x,y], h[y,x]}]] 

allsymops[s_,t_] := allsymops[s,t] =  
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Outer[allsyms[#1,#2]&,s,t]]] 

Clear[reach]; 
reach[{}] = {} 
reach[{n_}] := reach[n] = {n} 
reach[s_] := reach[s] = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[ 
 Table[allsymops[reach[i],reach[Complement[s,i]]],  
  {i,Complement[Subsets[s],{ {},s}]}]]]
```

The general idea here is to avoid calculating powers (which are 
expensive and non-commutative), while at the same time using the 
commutativity/associativity of addition/multiplication to reduce the 
cardinality of reach[].

Code above also available at:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/playground.m#L20

along with literally gigabytes of other useless code, data, and humor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question lays in the command [`Groupings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html). This allows you to create a binary tree of a list. The binary tree is very usefull as each of the operations you allow `Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power` take two arguments. Eg.

```
In>  Groupings[3,2]
Out> {List[List[1,2],3],List[1,List[2,3]]}
```

Thus all we need to do is replace `List` with any combination of the allowed operations.

However, `Groupings` seems to be almighty as it has an option to do this. Imagine you have two functions `foo` and `bar` and both take `2` arguments, then you can make all combinations as :

```
In>  Groupings[3,{foo->2,bar->2}]
Out> {foo[foo[1,2],3],foo[1,foo[2,3]],foo[bar[1,2],3],foo[1,bar[2,3]],
      bar[foo[1,2],3],bar[1,foo[2,3]],bar[bar[1,2],3],bar[1,bar[2,3]]}
```

Now it is possible to count the amount of combinations we have :

```
In>  Groupings[Permutations[#],
               {Plus->2,Subtract->2,Times->2,Divide->2,Power->2}
              ] &@ {a,b,c,d,e};
In>  Length@%
In>  DeleteDuplicates@%%
In>  Length@%
Out> 1050000
Out>  219352
```

This means that for 5 distinct numbers, we have 219352 unique combinations.

Sadly, many of these combinations cannot be evaluated due to overflow, division by zero or underflow. However, it is not evident which ones to remove. The value `a^(b^(c^(d^e)))` could be humongous, or just small. Fractional powers could result in perfect roots and divisions by large numbers can become perfect.

```
In>  Groupings[Permutations[#],
               {Plus->2,Subtract->2,Times->2,Divide->2,Power->2}
              ] &@ {2, 3, 4};
In>  Union[Cases[%, _?(IntegerQ[#] && # >= 0 &)]];
In>  Split[%, #2 - #1 <= 1 &][[1]]
Out> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```