# Smallest positive integer not calculable given digits, possible to due in non exponential time?

Tags: algorithm

I was given this as a challenge: Given a certain amount of a single digit, so say 4 8s, find the smallest positive integer not calculable with the standard operations (+,-,*,/) and any combination of parenthesis.

I've taken a look at these two posts: [Algorithm for permutations of operators and operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947937/algorithm-for-permutations-of-operators-and-operands/3948113#3948113)
[smallest integer not obtainable from {2,3,4,5,6,7,8} (Mathematica)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977107/smallest-integer-not-obtainable-from-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-mathematica)

But I still don't understand how to do this problem. The first link seems to be some algorithm where you store every every number calculable given the digits, and then do a simple lookup. This brute force method seems okay albeit somewhat slow.

Is there a pattern that can be used that I'm not seeing? I thought about a DP approach, but even with DP, you'd have to be trying every single combination for all the digits, operands, and parenthesis which just seems way too slow. With the solution given in the first link, it seems like you're headed towards a exponential solution.

So for example if you have 4 different digits, you have 3 operands you need to fill out in your equation. N O N O N O N. Each of those operands can take 4 separate values, so you have 4*4*4 or 4^3 combinations to try, which is exponential.

Comment: There is no smallest integer, so as far as I can tell, there is no solution to this. Is there anything that you didn't specify in your question?

Comment: The first link you gave asks the same question as this, and has a high-quality, accepted and heavily upvoted answer. You don't like the answer, but unless you ask something specific and different to the original question, I would expect your question to be closed.

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't know...maybe you can interpret OP as "Any algorithm has a better performance than the accepted answer in the links?", then would it be okay?

Comment: I know the answer is given in the first link, but that is for 4 digits and in the answer he says that the problem is small enough to brute force.But imagine in this problem if I gave you 1000 2s. Now this brute force method seems way too slow?

Comment: @moreON, the smallest positive integer not calculable given the digits I gave in my example (4 8s) is 5. So there is an answer.

Comment: @Kevin Your question says nothing about positive integers, that may be what's missing.

Comment: Oops you're right, I forgot about that part! Updated the question.

Comment: This answer proves that the problem is a generalization of an NP-hard problem, and so unlikely to have a known non-exponential-time solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564543/writing-an-algorithm-to-decide-whether-a-target-number-can-be-reached-with-a-set

Comment: Thanks Paul! I thought it might be NP-hard, but I couldn't remember which problem to reduce it to. Good to know!