# Given a string of ints and an objective number print out all the possible combinations of tuples and their results

Tags: haskell

Well, i do understand that the whole point of haskell (mostly) is the advantage of using recursivity to build more complex functions out of simpler ones, I have a function named pairs that from a String of ints returns all the possible tuple combinations, I then have another function called operations which with a given tuple, prints out all of the possible operations the two numbers can do (*,+,-,/), now comes the part i can't get round my head:

```
-- Find all possible 2-combinations of the elements of xs.
pairs :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
pairs xs = [(x, y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys]

operations :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int, Char, Int)]
operations (x, y) =
    [ (x, y, '+', x + y) ] ++
    [ (x, y, '*', x * y) ] ++
    [ (x, y, '-', x - y) | x > y, (x/=4 && y/=2) ] ++
    [ (x, y, '/', x `div` y) | x >= y, x `mod` y == 0]
```

I'm trying to implement a function that given a string of ints and an objective number (ultimate aim is to obtain that number with the String of ints) I print out all the possible combinations of tuples and their results, e.g.)

```
solve ( 100 , [1,4,5] , [] )

[ ( 100 , [5,5] , [(1,4,'+',5)] ),take first tuple 1,4 add and subs into "new tuple"5,5
( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ),
( 100 , [6,4] , [(1,5,'+',6)] ),
( 100 , [4,4] , [(5,1,'-',4)] ),
( 100 , [9,1] , [(4,5,'+',9)] ),
( 100 , [1,1] , [(5,4,'-',1)] ),
( 100 , [20,1] , [(4,5,'*',20)] ) ]
```

Im confused as to how to approach this, as i know i already have a function that prints all possible operations on a tuple and one that produces all the tuples yet i can't see how to combine them, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

I see your solution and makes sense but its too late for me to start from scratch,

i have done this:

```
solve(n,ns) = [ e | ns' <- pairs ns
                      , e   <- operations ns']
```

( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ), is what i want

I see, i want to try my way to work as it seems a bit different and i get confused after the 2nd where, i'm still a bit terrible at Haskell.
So this is what my functions do: 
pairs: when given a String returns all possible tuples: pairs [1,2,3,4,5,6] would return [(1,2),(1,3)...etc]
operations takes a tuple and returns all possible operations with that tuple (has to be positive integer result else we don't want it) and finally

```
solve(n,ns) = [ e | ns' <- pairs ns
                      , e   <- operations ns']
```

takes n the objective number, ns a string of 6 +ints and so far returns a string with all combinations of the tuples printed such as: [(3,'+',4,7),(3,´*´,4,12)...etc] however i want it printing at each stage:

```
[n,(result of tuple operation,string number)(tuple operation)]
eg ( 100 , [5,5] , [(1,4,'+',5)] ),take first tuple 1,4 add and subs into "new tuple"5,5
( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ),
( 100 , [6,4] , [(1,5,'+',6)] ),
```

Comment: Can you provide the type signatures of the functions you already have, along with the one that you are trying to make? This would make your question much clearer.

Comment: Sure, i'll edit the main post

Comment: I'm confused by your example outputs for the `solve` function. None of the operations actually yield the target number 100. Also, what does the second element of each result tuple mean?

Comment: yes im not finding that just yet, im just finding all possible operations and printing them out in this fashion, so say in ( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ), the 3 which is the result is stored back in the tuple [3,5] as this is a new tuple on which again recursively I can use operations (is my wild guess), am I making much sense?

Comment: so, from an intial string of ints  can produce all tuples, from the operations carried on those tuple each tuple produces a new set of numbers which in turn can be used to create a new tuple. Maybe i should've said this first; but the aim is to get to an objective number using add,subb, div, mult on a string of numbers, this is what i have to do but i find this much more complex and longwinded http://www.glc.us.es/~jalonso/vestigium/i1m2012-problema-del-concurso-cifras-y-letras-en-haskell/

Comment: Are you *required* to use tuples? I ask because tuples are not very recursion-friendly. Lists on the other hand are much more so.

Comment: Also, are repetitions allowed? For example, can you use `(5, 5, '*', 25)` as a possible candidate?

Comment: yep, im required to use tuples, and i would guess repetitions are allowed, why not as long as I get to the correct result

Comment: this is what the final output should be i think
`[3,7,13,19,23,29]
[4,13,19,23,29]
[25,13,19,23]
[32,25,23]
[800,23]
[823]
[ ]
[(7,3,'',
4)]
[(7,3,'',
4),(29,4,'',
25)]
[(7,3,'',
4),(29,4,'',
25),(13,19,'+',32)]
[(7,3,'',
4),(29,4,'',
25),(13,19,'+',32),(32,25,'*',800)]
[(7,3,'',
4),(29,4,'',
25),(13,19,'+',32),(32,25,'*',800),(800,23,'+',823)]`

Comment: blergh not very clear, this should make it clearer http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/txtv.jpg/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem. What follows is an outline of a relatively straight-forward Haskell-esque solution. Note that is uses algebraic data types, so you'll want to become familiar with that if you aren't already.

Note: This is a somewhat involved problem. My solution (which is relatively clean) is 55 lines long.

The first step is to define the appropriate data type for your problem. I will choose the following:

```
data Expr = Lit Int
   | Plus Expr Expr
   | Times Expr Expr
   | Minus Expr Expr
   | Divide Expr Expr
  deriving Show
```

A value of type `Expr` is an expression tree that is composed of four binary operations and has integers at its leaves. Using this definition you'll want to define the following functions:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int       -- "evaluate" a expression

exprs :: [Int] -> [Expr]  -- derive all expression trees whose literals come from
                          -- a list of integers
```

Then finding expressions which evaluate to a particular number is just:

```
findexprs :: [Int] -> Int -> [Expr]
findexprs xs y = filter (\e -> eval e == y) $ exprs xs
```

## Writing `eval`

The `eval` function is going to be a straight-forward case analysis:

```
eval (Lit x) = x
eval (Plus a b) = (eval a) + (eval b)
eval (Minus a b) = (eval a) - (eval b)
...
```

Hint: for division, look up the `quot` function.

## Writing `exprs`

The first couple of cases for `exprs` is pretty easy:

```
exprs :: [Int] -> [Expr]
exprs []  = []
exprs [x] = [ Lit x ]
exprs xs  = ...
```

When there is only one number in the list, the only expression you can create is with `Lit`.

The final case of `exprs` goes something like this:

1. divide `xs` into two sub-lists: `left` and `right`
2. formulate an expression tree using the list `left`
3. formulate an expression tree using the list `right`
4. combine the two expression trees with a binary operator

Steps 2 and 3 are just recursive calls to the `exprs` function. Step 4 just iterates through all of the possible binary operators. You can use a list comprehension for this.

For step 1 we need to find all the ways of splitting a list into two sub-lists.
That is, we need to define a function:

```
parts :: [Int] -> [ ([Int], [Int]) ]
```

For example, `parts [1,2] = [ ([1,2],[]), ([1],[2]), ([2],[1]), ([], [1,2]) ]`.

Of course, `parts` can be defined recursively, and the trick is to find the pattern:

```
parts [] = [ ([],[]) ]
parts (x:xs) = ...???...
```

A hint here is to ask yourself how you would form `parts (x:xs)` from `parts xs`.

## Caveats

I've left out some implementation details. First of all, if you really want to implement division correctly you'll probably have to re-consider this type signature for `eval`:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
```

Initially to get things working you may want to leave out division operator. Then you may want to read up on the `Maybe` data type.

I've also left out details in the definition of `exprs`. There's an infinite-loop pitfall (which can be easily side-stepped) lurking in steps I've outlined.

Good luck!

## Comments

(Since SO doesn't like long-running threads in the comments, I'll address the OP's questions here.)

As I mentioned before, there are many ways to solve this problem, e.g. see
[Algorithm for permutations of operators and operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947937/algorithm-for-permutations-of-operators-and-operands)

This approach is more complicated, but it is a useful decompositional pattern
which you will see widely used in Haskell. It also takes care to separate
the following concerns:

1. generating the possible trees (the `exprs` function)
2. evaluating an expression tree (the `eval` function)
3. find the trees of interest (`filter ...`)

Your approach combines the first two concerns. That may not be a problem
if you are just solving this problem, but suppose you change the criteria
for a legal expression. For instance, what if numbers in the list can be reused
multiple times (currently numbers may only be used once.) Or, what if you don't
need to use all of the numbers? These variations would only require changing
the `exprs` function.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! Yes, the "backgorund" is indeed trees, im going to wrap my head round some of these concepts i'd never seen before and bugger you if i get stuck ha! Thanks again

Comment: Question: I have managed to do the first functions in "my way" which i see clearly how they work and understand, now although i am starting to understand what you're suggesting it seems far more complicated, is there no way of using what I had initially done? Again, thanks for such a brilliant explanation and solution

Comment: I see your solution and makes sense but its too late for me to start from scratch, as much as I like haskell i don't think i will use it in a while, i have done this

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I see your solution and makes sense but its too late for me to start from scratch,

i have done this:

solve (n,ns) = [ e | ns' <- pairs ns
                      , e   <- operations ns'] 

( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ), is what i wanr

this function only prints out ,[(4,1,'-',3) with all iterations, i have tried concatenating the number but i get shouted at by GHCi with : and ++

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand what you are trying to do.

When reading the following code you should run `choose1` and `pairs` on sample lists of ints to see what they do, e.g. `choose1 [2,5,7]` and `pairs [1,2,3]`.

`phi` returns all the possible evaluations as a pair `(x,hs)` where `x` is the final result and `hs` is the history of operations (a list). Note that the history is backwards - the first element of the `hs` list is the last operation that was performed.

Each element of the `hs` list is itself a tuple of the form `(Int,Char,Int,Int)` -- e.g. `(3,'-',4,-1)` and denotes the operation `3-4 => -1`.

As a test, try: `head $ solve [3,7,13,19,23,29] 823`

```
import Data.List (inits,tails)

always _ _ = True
canDivide a b = (b /= 0) && (a `mod` b) == 0

ops :: [ ( Int -> Int -> Int, Char, Int -> Int -> Bool) ]
ops = [ ((+), '+', always),
        ((-), '-', always),
        ((*), '*', always),
        (div, '/', canDivide) ]

choose1 xs = zip xs zs
  where zs = zipWith (++) (inits xs) (tail $ tails xs)

pairs xs = [ (x,y,r2) | (x,r1) <- choose1 xs, (y,r2) <- choose1 r1 ]

phi xs = go xs []
    where
      go [] hs  = []
      go [x] hs = [ (x,hs) ]
      go xs hs  = [ (x,h) |
          (a,b,rest) <- pairs xs,
          (op,name,can) <- ops,
          can a b,
          let c = op a b,
          (x,h) <- go (c:rest) ((a,name,b,c):hs) ]

solve :: [Int] -> Int -> [ (Int, [ (Int, Char, Int, Int) ] ) ]
solve xs n = filter (\(x,hs) -> (x == n)) $ phi xs
```

Comment: I see, i want to try my way to work as it seems a bit different and i get confused after the 2md where, i'm still a bit terrible at Haskell.

Comment: eddited my main post again

Comment: but you are totally right in your approach, problem is my incompetence with haskell at this stage.