# Algorithm which determines required signs for arithmetical operation

Tags: algorithm

I have no idea how to Google this out so I would like to ask you guys if you know is there such an algorithm, which would determine what kind of signs you need to put between numbers in order to get given result.

For example, you input 4 numbers: 8 9 2 1. The last number is the result. So the answer would be 8-9+2=1. Is there such an algorithm, maybe you know its name so I could Google it out and read about it?

Comment: Try all combinations until one works?!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your question is NP-complete.

Comment: This is repeated question and answer is given here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947937/algorithm-for-permutations-of-operators-and-operands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).

You generate all possible candidates for the solution and check each of them to see whether they satisfy the constraints.

Comment: @WheelPot there is, eg. dynamic programming, backtrack-search, greedy search (i.e local search) and so on, still  they do not guarantee optimal solution in polynomial time

Comment: In real life you only need sophistication if you have a problem to solve. With small lists, the brute-force approach is perfect. If you have large lists, and some good constraints (e.g.: small integers, and just + or -) you can apply some techniques (e.g.: dynamic programming) to have a better algorithmic complexity.